Youtube embed api - Is there any control over the new auto dubbing features?
When embedding a youtube video, I can set the caption language preference with cc_lang_pref, but I can't figure out a way to set the audio language given that a lot of videos are now automatically dubbed. I'd like an option to always set them to their original language, with the user being able to change it through the controls if they like similar to how the caption works. But I can't find these options in the api. Does this exist? If not, are there any plans for it in the future?
